# Numerical calculation of berry curvature of Haldane model

Tags: condensed-matter, computational-physics, electronic-band-theory, graphene, berry-pancharatnam-phase

I'm currently trying to simulate the Haldane model of graphene and am looking into the calculation of Berry curvature of the finite lattice. I'm using a tight-binding model of graphene with nearest-neighbour and complex next nearest-neighbour hopping only, with Hamiltonian

[image].

I use the Kubo Formula for the Berry curvature, which is essentially

[image]

with the integral removed.

Using mathematica code I've come up with this figure of the curvature plotted over the Brillouin zone for t2=0.1 (the Haldane hopping)

[image]

The graph should instead follow the density plot shown below

[image]

The code I use is quite simple and is given below. I can't see anything wrong with the logic of the code itself and I also haven't seen any papers calculating the Berry curvature in this direct fashion. I was wondering if someone could point out any errors in my code logic / use of this formula. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
a = {{1/Sqrt[3], 0}, {-1/(2*Sqrt[3]), 1/2}, {-1/(2*Sqrt[3]), -1/2}};
b = {{0, 1}, {-Sqrt[3]/2, -1/2}, {Sqrt[3]/2, -1/2}};
kvec = {kx, ky};
Sum[PauliMatrix[1]*Cos[kvec . a[[i]]] - 
    PauliMatrix[2]*Sin[kvec . a[[i]]] + 
    2*t2*PauliMatrix[3]*Sin[kvec . b[[i]]], {i, 3}] + 
  delta*PauliMatrix[3];
h0[kx_, ky_, delta_, t2_] = %;
h0[KX, KY, DELTA, T2] // MatrixForm


phi = Pi/2;
a1 = {0, 1/Sqrt[3]};
a2 = {-1/2, -1/(2*Sqrt[3])};
a3 = {1/2, -1/(2*Sqrt[3])};
kvec = {kx, ky};
nvalue = 1;
{{-2*t*(Cos[kvec . a1 - phi] + Cos[kvec . a2 - phi] + 
       Cos[kvec . a3 - phi]) + del, 
   Exp[I*kvec . a1] + Exp[I*kvec . a2] + 
    Exp[I*kvec . a3]}, {Exp[-I*kvec . a1] + Exp[-I*kvec . a2] + 
    Exp[-I*kvec . a3], -2*
     t*(Cos[kvec . a1 + phi] + Cos[kvec . a2 + phi] + 
       Cos[kvec . a3 + phi]) - del}};
h1[kx_, ky_, del_, t_] = % ;

kxrange = N[Range[-2*Pi + Pi/100, 2*Pi - Pi/100, 4*Pi/100]];
kyrange = N[Range[-2*Pi + Pi/100, 2*Pi - Pi/100, 4*Pi/100]];
t2val = 0.1;
phival = Pi/2;
deltaval = 0.0;
h0[KX, KY, deltaval, t2val];
ham = %;
Eigenvectors[h0[KX, KY, deltaval, t2val]];
anaeigvecs = %;
Eigenvalues[h0[KX, KY, deltaval, t2val]];
anaeigvals = %;
I*((ConjugateTranspose[anaeigvecs[[1]]] . D[ham, KX] . 
        anaeigvecs[[2]])*(ConjugateTranspose[anaeigvecs[[2]]] . 
        D[ham, KY] . 
        anaeigvecs[[1]]) - (ConjugateTranspose[anaeigvecs[[1]]] . 
        D[ham, KY] . 
        anaeigvecs[[2]])*(ConjugateTranspose[anaeigvecs[[2]]] . 
        D[ham, KX] . anaeigvecs[[1]]))/(anaeigvals[[1]] - 
      anaeigvals[[2]])^2;
berry[KX_, KY_] = %;
Plot3D[Re[berry[KX, KY]], {KX, -2*Pi, 2*Pi}, {KY, -2*Pi, 2*Pi}, 
 PlotRange -> Full]
```

Comment: As per the [comp-physics tag info](https://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/computational-physics/info), we don't debug code on this site.